# INSERT IMAGE INTO TABLE (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

I'm loading a script that creates tables using Hibernate

```
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/database/initial.sql</property>
```

So inside /database i have a mysql script that creates a table and inserts a user.

My problem is. How do I put a insert an image for him? I tried LOAD_IMAGE but I don't know what's the directory.

Any help?

```
   -- Users
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hashedPassword` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `image` mediumblob,
  `team` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userRole` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`),
  KEY `fkteam_idx` (`team`),
  KEY `fkrole_idx` (`userRole`),
  CONSTRAINT `fkrole` FOREIGN KEY (`userRole`) REFERENCES `user_roles` (`user_role_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkteam` FOREIGN KEY (`team`) REFERENCES `team` (`idteam`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `name`, `hashedPassword`, `enabled`, `ìmage`, `userRole`) VALUES ('admin', 'admin', 'somepassword', '1' , HOW DO I PUT THE IMAGE HERE?? , '1');
```

Comment: If you are using Hibernate, then why are you showing us a raw MySQL query?  Most likely, you can model the image as a binary BLOB in a class somewhere.  Hibernate will do the heavy lifting of figuring out how to do the insert.  You are reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: this is a script to create the initial tables and insert data. I need the first user to have an image

Comment: Take a step back and don't worry about your business requirements.  You said you are using Hibernate.  Can you show us the entity for your users?

Comment: do you know or not?